# Python3 argparse set_defaults doesn't take string as option name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm new to argparse, so this may be fundamental.

I prefer to have all of my string constants defined once (`blah = 'foo'`), and then use that throughout the code. When I get to `set_defaults`, it seems that I'm limited to kwarg-type parameters.

That is, `parser.set_defaults(NUM=ONE)` doesn't treat NUM as a string. Here's a fuller example:

```
ONE = 'one'
TWO = 'two'
SIX = 'six'
NUMBER_OPTS = [ONE, TWO, SIX]
NUM = 'num'

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
pform = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
for opt in NUMBER_OPTS:
    pform.add_argument('--'+opt, dest=NUM, action='store_const', const=opt)
parser.set_defaults(NUM=ONE) # Can't find a syntax to make this DWIM
args = parser.parse_args()
print("%s is %s" % (NUM, vars(args)[NUM]))
```

So while `add_argument` takes a string as a destination, `set_defaults` doesn't.

Comment: Your `NUM` doesn't work as an attribute name either, as in `args.NUM`.  You either had to change `args` to a dictionary and use `NUM` as key, or use `getattr(args, NUM)` (as `argparse` does internally).

Comment: keyword arguments, including the `**kwargs` form are described at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use dictionary expansion:

```
parser.set_defaults(**{NUM: ONE})
```

Comment: This is a good one. I was also trying to figure out a solution to this problem... This solution is very elegant!

Comment: Thanks, that does it. Too bad this roundabout method is required, but my pythonic instinct has improved a notch.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic, the signature for this method is `set_defaults(self, **kwargs)`.  `argparse` uses the `**kwargs` style alot.  For example: `add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs)`.   So familiarize yourself with that Python usage.  And look up the source code for these methods in `argparse.py`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for your comment. I did look up the source code, but the source code doesn't tell me @Daniel's solution of `**{NUM: ONE}`. In fact, that is a subtle and obscure syntax, in so much as it doesn't have an obvious name, and you must already know of it to guess it. I also can't recall another language where a string var must be double-interpreted before it will pass correctly to a method. (Here it's (1) use it as a dict key in an anonymous dict, and (2) unpack the dict in the method call.)

Comment: @QuantumMechanic, It's similar to the two ways of defining a dictionary, d = {'one':1} and d = dict(one=1). And the third `dict(**{'one':1}). Note how the dictionary displays.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html)'s `default` argument to do that:

```
pform.add_argument('--'+opt, dest=NUM, action='store_const', const=opt, default=NUM)
```

Comment: Yes, this works for the general case. For my specific example, I'm iterating through a list of option names, that all have the same destination. I assume the last option name processed would be the default. (For dict keys instead of a list, no order is expected, and without imposing an order, I wouldn't know ahead of time which default was retained.)

Comment: @QuantumMechanic, `set_defaults` iterated though the Actions (arguments) in the order they were defined, and (re)sets the `default` of its `dest` to the new value.  `parse_args` sets defaults at the start of parsing, using the same list of Actions.  With repeated `dest`, the first is used.

Answer (score 1):

Running your code with a little modification:

```
In [35]: ONE = 'one'
    ...: TWO = 'two'
    ...: SIX = 'six'
    ...: NUMBER_OPTS = [ONE, TWO, SIX]
    ...: NUM = 'num'
    ...: alist = []
    ...: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ...: pform = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
    ...: for opt in NUMBER_OPTS:
    ...:     a = pform.add_argument('--'+opt, dest=NUM, action='store_const', co
    ...: nst=opt)
    ...:     alist.append(a)

In [37]: alist
Out[37]: 
[_StoreConstAction(option_strings=['--one'], dest='num', nargs=0, const='one', default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),
 _StoreConstAction(option_strings=['--two'], dest='num', nargs=0, const='two', default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None),
 _StoreConstAction(option_strings=['--six'], dest='num', nargs=0, const='six', default=None, type=None, choices=None, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

`alist` contains pointers to the 3 `Action` objects created by the `add_argument` statement.  I could have gotten the same list from `pform._group_actions`, since these actions were added to that group.

By setting the `dest` explicitly, it is `'num'` rather than the `opt` (derived from the long flag):

```
In [40]: alist[0].dest
Out[40]: 'num'
```

`parser.set_defaults(num=ONE)` sets the `default` attribute of Actions with `dest='one'` to `'one'.

```
In [45]: [a.default for a in alist]
Out[45]: ['one', 'one', 'one']
In [46]: [a.const for a in alist]
Out[46]: ['one', 'two', 'six']
```

This default could also have been defined in the loop with:

```
pform.add_argument('--'+opt, dest=NUM, default=ONE, const=opt, , action='store_const')
```

It would also have been sufficient to the `default` for the first one in the list, leaving the others to be the default default `None`.  That's a consequence of how defaults are set at the start of parsing.

I can verify that with:

```
In [47]: alist[1].default=TWO
In [48]: alist[2].default=SIX
In [49]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[49]: Namespace(num='one')
```

The `const` works as intended:

```
In [50]: parser.parse_args(['--two'])
Out[50]: Namespace(num='two')
```

The `num` value in the parsed Namespace can be fetched in several ways:

```
In [51]: _.num                   # as attribute
Out[51]: 'two'
In [52]: getattr(Out[50],'num')   # NUM works here
Out[52]: 'two'
In [53]: vars(Out[50])['num']     # dictionary, NUM works here
Out[53]: 'two'
```

(`_` is the previous answer.  It is also stored in the `Out` list.)

Another trick is to define a Namespace object before parsing.  Any values defined there have priority over defaults.  Note that the `Namespace(...)` definition has the same syntax as `set_defaults`:

```
In [54]: ns = argparse.Namespace(num='four')
In [55]: parser.parse_args([], namespace=ns)
Out[55]: Namespace(num='four')
In [56]: parser.parse_args(['--six'], namespace=ns)
Out[56]: Namespace(num='six')
```

Python, like most languages, makes a distinction between symbols and strings.  Only strings are quoted.  Symbols can be used to name variables, object attributes, and as function keywords.

In your case `NUM` is a symbol, `'num'` is a string.  In `dest=NUM`, `dest` is the symbol, the value of `NUM` is the string value.  In `alist[0].dest`, `dest` is the attribute name, its value is the string `'num'`.

But `argparse` takes that `a.dest` value, and uses it to define an attribute in the `args` namespace.  That is why `num` can be used as an attribute name below:

```
In [58]: args = parser.parse_args(['--six'])
In [59]: args
Out[59]: Namespace(num='six')
In [60]: args.num
Out[60]: 'six'
```

`argparse` actually uses `getattr` and `setattr` to read and set the values of these attributes:

```
In [61]: getattr(args, 'num')
Out[61]: 'six'
In [62]: getattr(args, alist[0].dest)
Out[62]: 'six'
```

This imposes the few assumptions about the `dest` values; they don't even have to be valid attribute names.

I pointed out in a comment, the dictionaries can also be defined with symbols and with strings:

```
In [63]: {'num':'one'}
Out[63]: {'num': 'one'}
In [64]: dict(num='one')
Out[64]: {'num': 'one'}
```

Keyword arguments, including the open ended `**kwargs`, also cross the symbol/string boundary:

```
In [65]: def foo(**kwargs):
    ...:     print(kwargs)
    ...:     
In [66]: foo(num='one')    # keyword input
{'num': 'one'}
In [67]: foo(**Out[63])    # expand a dictionary
{'num': 'one'}
```

So while Python makes a distinction between symbols and strings, it has various ways of crossing the boundary.

---

`NUM=ONE` runs, but defines an `args.NUM` attribute.

```
In [72]: parser.set_defaults(NUM=ONE)
In [73]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[73]: Namespace(NUM='one', num='one')
In [74]: parser.parse_args([]).NUM
Out[74]: 'one'
```

Now let's get rid of that `NUM` default

```
In [76]: parser._defaults
Out[76]: {'NUM': 'one', 'num': 'one'}
In [78]: del parser._defaults['NUM']
In [79]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[79]: Namespace(num='one')
```

---

```
def set_defaults(self, **kwargs):
    # original method, takes keyword-value or **dict
    self._defaults.update(kwargs)

    # if these defaults match any existing arguments, replace
    # the previous default on the object with the new one
    for action in self._actions:
        if action.dest in kwargs:
            action.default = kwargs[action.dest]

def set_defaults(parser, adict):
    # function version that takes a dictionary rather than **kwargs
    parser._defaults.update(adict)
    for action in parser._actions:
        if action.dest in adict:
            action.default = adict[action.dest]
```

Use in

```
In [80]: set_defaults(parser, {NUM: 'three'})  # diff value
In [81]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[81]: Namespace(num='three')
```

Admittedly this doesn't change much; just eliminates the `**` expansion.  There's just no way in Python of making (...NUM=ONE...) mean (... 'num':ONE...).

Maybe this whole dictionary bussiness is a redherring.  We could instead pass tuples of dest and default

```
def set_defaults(parser, alist):
    # function version that takes a list of tuples
    for dest, default in alist: # iterate on tuples
        for action in parser._actions:
            if action.dest == dest:
                action.default = default

In [83]: set_defaults(parser, [(NUM, SIX)])
In [84]: parser.parse_args([])
Out[84]: Namespace(num='six')
```

In other words we just need a way of pairing a `dest` value with a `default` value.  It doesn't have to be a dictionary `key:value` mapping.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, the symbol/string boundary is rather fluid. I don't know of any other language where it is so easy to get a symbol into a string. Perl allows "autoquoting" in hash keys, or on the left side of the fat comma (`=>`), but that is documented as quoting -- if the key is a symbol, it must have a Perl sigil (e.g., `$key`) to be looked up. But Python's "It's a symbol! It's a key!" behavior is disappointing.

Comment: The ambiguity of assuming an unquoted string should be a string literal, when it's obviously known to the parser as a defined symbol, still catches me out. Yes, Python would be wordier if all parameter names had to be quoted in the call, like `foo('this'=one, 'that'=two)`. It would also be less ambiguous, and I wouldn't need work-arounds like `foo(**{this:one, that:two})`.

Comment: @QuantumMechanic; I've explored some alternative versions of `set_defaults`.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I see how I could have done it differently and avoided the symbol/string issue with `default=ONE`. Thank you for your clear analysis of the options and the effect on the state of the object.